# where is qt5 designer

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, qt5

I updated an Ubuntu 12.04 machine to 14.04.

The 12.04 install just had qt4, and had

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/designer
```

The 14.04 install has qt5, but I cannot get a

`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/designer` executable
installed.

I have `libqt5designer5` and `libqt5designercomponents5` installed,
and I get the libs but not the application.

I also have a bunch of `qtquick` packages installed.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 37):

```
sudo apt-get install qttools5-dev-tools
```

solved the problem.

The designer is included in the package "qttools5-dev-tools".

```
[$ nbviewer]$ apt-file search /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/designer 
qttools5-dev-tools: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/designer
```

Comment: That worked for me too. It should probably be marked as the answer.

Comment: Worked also on 16.04. 
+1 for marking this as the accepted answer.

Comment: In 16.04 `/usr/bin/designer` is just a symlink to `qtchooser`. It decides by the link name which tool to start. If you have multiple Qt versions  installed you can give it one of the versions given by `qtchooser -l`. E.g. `designer -qt5` will open the Qt5 version of designer.

Answer (score 7):

In the library packed are no binaries for the designer application.

Install the designer with

```
sudo apt-get install qtcreator
```

[image]

Comment: Hi,  thanks very much A.B.   qtcreator is installed, and is using qt5.  I can open one of their examples, but the design button on left sidebar stays greyed out.    --Kate

Comment: I will check this tomorrow

Comment: The button is only active, if there is a open ui-file. I will add a screenshot.

Comment: Do you have /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/designer on your system ? If so, could you do dpkg -S on it and let me know what pkg it came from ?

Comment: This is not what was asked for and doesn’t help user that use another or no idea at all. Plus it doesn’t even work if `qttools5-dev-tools` isn’t installed, so this basically boils down to @ptmono  answer.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who is working on `PyQT5` on NVIDIA Jetson Tegra X2 (TX2) running Ubuntu `16.04`, this is the directory to find QT5 Designer:

```
/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/designer
```

Comment: In my case: `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/designer`

Answer (score 0):

I was doing:

```
sudo apt-get install qttools5-dev-tools
```

I was not getting any results so instead I tried this and it worked:

```
sudo apt-get install qttools5-dev
```

This little difference has supposed some hours for me, I hope this post will help you.