# Cant find Qt5Designer, qt5svg and qt5x11extras

Tags: qt, c++, qt-creator, qt5

I'm trying to install KLatexFormula and it's cmake script is giving the error that it cant find the package config files Qt5DesignerConfig.cmake and qt5designer-config.cmake.

Cmake asked me to add the prefix of Qt5Designer to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH. I found the path to Qt5Designer with a quick

```
apt-files search Qt5Designer
```

The file I was looking for showed up under the path

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5Designer/Qt5DesignerConfig.cmake
```

under qttools5-dev package. I believe this is the correct spot, so I added the prefix path with

```
export QT_CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake"
```

and the path shows up if I check the command

```
export
```

However, building the cmake file again gave me the same missing packages. In the process of trying to work out what was wrong I went

```
cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake
```

At this point I saw that there was no Qt5Designer entry in this folder. My qttools5-dev is completely up to date. Anyone know how I can fix it?

And I have tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/651461/where-is-qt5-designer) already and get the same search results as that answer.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install qttools5-dev-tools` .... ← https://askubuntu.com/questions/651461/where-is-qt5-designer

Comment: @KnudLarsen Already seen that post and tried it, says that package is already at the newest version (5.6.1-2build1~~xenialoverlay1~1)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To anyone else having the issue with qttools5-dev-tools not installing Qt Designer stuff try

```
sudo apt install qttools5-dev
```

instead (note there is no -tools at the end).

I was also lacking qt5svg and qt5x11extras, and these were solved with

```
sudo apt install libqt5svg5-dev
```

and

```
sudo apt install libqt5x11extras5-dev
```

respectively.

Comment: Working for build from source ksnip 1.8.0 to solve this: "If "Qt5Svg"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed."

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who has this issue you would need to install the following:

```
apt install libqt5charts5-dev
install qtbase5-dev libqt5x11extras5-dev libqt5svg5-dev qtdeclarative5-dev libqt5charts5-dev libmuparser-dev
```